# Rails3 - email template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am fetching email content from database and storing it in variable and passsing it to email template.

i.e:

```
@email_content = Email.find(1) 
@email_content = @email_content.content
```

My content is like this: `"hi, how are you doing, thanks"`. With html `<br/>` tags in between the content.

Problem is, I'm getting the mail as plain text, the html tags are not working.

Could someone help me solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view file you need to put this

```
<%= @email_content.html_safe %>
```